# What does this warning message mean? 'img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why am I getting this warning?

> warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/img-has-alt

It's showing line number 13 but there is nothing props is using.

Comment: define the `alt='some value'` with img, check the meaning of that: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp

Comment: alt prop means alt property.

Comment: it means it needs an alt prop, like <img src="..." alt="...">

Comment: http://html.com/attributes/img-alt/

Comment: It is worth noting that screenreaders will likely announce that the object is an image. Including phrases like "picture of..." or "image of..." in the `alt` attribute may lead to cases of the screenreader saying confusing things like "image of image of".

Comment: alt is needed in case images fail to load. The text will be displayed over there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Images should have an alt property. The alternate property comes into picture in several cases like the card not getting downloaded, incompatible browsers, or the image getting corrupt. You need to pass in a prop called alt to the image.

Also, Alt tag is used by screen readers for visually impaired. Therefore it is considered as a good practice to always add a ALT tag to the image component.
[Accessibility](http://accessibility.psu.edu/images/imageshtml/)

Answer (score 42):

It means when you create an image in your HTML, you should include an `alt` attribute for the benefit of screen readers and text browsers.

```
<img src="url" alt="description of image">
```

Comment: Just to add more information, if you add description in alt attribute with following keywords "image, photo or picture" react gives following warning - "Redundant alt attribute. Screen-readers already announce `img` tags as an image. You don’t need to use the words `image`, `photo,` or `picture` (or any specified custom words) in the alt prop  jsx-a11y/img-redundant-alt"  React version - 16.8.3

Comment: something like that would not show the warning `<img src="url" alt="for sell">`

Comment: @Hunter I don't understand your comment. How is that different from what I say in my answer?

Comment: @Barmar because react will throw a warning sign if you include the word "image" in alt

Comment: @Hunter I didn't realize you were responding to the other comment.

Comment: @RahulRaut "description of image" was not intended literally, it was just a placeholder like "url" was.

Answer (score 12):

It means that your `<img>` tag **MUST** have an `alt` attribute on it like so:

`<img src="pathToYourImage.extension" alt="My Awesome Image">`

In case if the image isn't loaded then the text inside the `alt` attribute will be shown instead.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error. Basically, you should not include these words in `alt` attribute. `image or picture, or photo`

```js
// avoid using image or picture, or photo


// do
<img src="foo" alt="nice"/>.      // good


// don't
<img src="foo" alt="foo is coming "/>.    // bad
```

Answer (score 7):

It means that your image need a description and this is a property in the ***img tag*** called **alt** so use this as long as you write in JSX & React :

```
<img src={ImageImported} alt="description of image"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar error with this code.

```
    <img src={props.contacts.imgUrl}/>
```

Solution: Notice the alt= position on the image anchor outside the curved parenthesis

```
    <img src={props.contacts.imgUrl} alt=""/>
```

Comment: yes, I also make the alt attribute value empty and the warning goes off.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that you haven’t added the "alt" property. This property is mandatory, so you can not ignore it.

To get rid of this error you should set the **alt** attribute and pass some text there. It's like a description of your photo. This text will be used in cases when your picture is not loaded or when browser couldn't find your image by provided path (**src** attribute).

```
<img src="path_to_your_image" alt="alternative_text_of_your_image"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

in the alt attribute do not put the image or Image because those words are reserved for react

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

`<input type="image" img src = {'url'} alt="photo" />`

(I have used `` not the single quotation marks for the url)

Answer (score 0):

I had this an error when using ESLint in React for this:

```
<img src={frontDefault} />
```

Add this

```
alt=''
```

This is how it must be for it to work

```
<img src={frontDefault} alt='' />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was inside the REACT, and it happened because it was like this, <img src={{RedLed} } style={{width:'50px'}}/>, that way I was giving this error. The error was that I put two braces around the img call and I only needed one brace like that, <img src={RedLed} style={{width:'50px'}}/>

Answer (score 0):

The  element includes the alt property, which will prevent the image from having any alternate text,`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).